# Google Map API, what url's does it load?

Tags: javascript, security, google-maps

I am currently working on a locked down server where every URL I need to access needs to be whitelisted before I can access it.

Currently struggling with the Google MAP Api url i.e.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places

I takes around 35 seconds to load, so I am guessing there is a another URL somewhere it can't access hitting the above url timing out. Any idea's of the domains that need to be opened up to load the above file correctly ?

Comment: Look at your browser's network tools.

Comment: Also, that's a client-side API; it has nothing to do with a locked-down server.